# Convert int[] to byte[] type pointer in C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I require to convert int[] to byte[] pointer.
The above is required in order to be able to populate the entries of a WriteableBitmap pixel by pixel as below:

```
//previewBuffer1 is of type byte[]
WriteableBitmap wb1 = new WriteableBitmap(nVidWidth, nVidHeight);
int k=0;
// wb1.Pixels is of type int[] by default
byte* data = (byte*) wb1.Pixels;  // ****THIS DOESN'T WORK. THROWS ERROR. HOW CAN I ACCOMPLISH THIS***
for (int i=0; i<nVidHeight; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<nVidWidth; j++){
        byte grayscaleval = previewBuffer1[k];
        data [4*k] = grayscaleval ;
        data [4*k + 1] = grayscaleval ;
        data [4*k + 2] = grayscaleval ;
        k++;
    }
}
```

How do I get a byte* pointer for wb1.Pixels which is of type int[]?

Comment: why don't you perform operations with int[] ?? Why do you need a byte[]?

Comment: Well. WriteableBitmap stores the image information as RGBA in a single integer. To access the R,G,B channels, I require to access them as bytes...

Comment: I don't know if it's only me, but I am finding it extermally horrible to code image processing application on WP8. The intercompatibility between different APIs seems to be quite bad.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to treat each `int` in your array as sequence of bytes - how about  [`BitConverter.GetBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de8fssa4.aspx)?

```
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
```

---

If you want to avoid array copying etc, use `unsafe` which allows pointers (you'd need to tick the "Allow unsafe code" checkbox in project properties):

```
unsafe static void UnsafeConvert(int value)
{
    byte* bytes = (byte*)&value;
    byte first = bytes[0];
    ...
}
```

Comment: You understood my question correctly. But I require to save three bytes at the original int location. The one you mentioned would store the bytes at a different location.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that such an option of unsafe casting exists. I have anyways solved it using another technique, you can find it as a reply to this question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by your loop because I think it has a few problems...but it looks like you are trying to strip the alpha component of RGBA data.  Why not do something like:

Assuming you have:
  1. a byte [] you want to store RGB data without the Alpha component
  2. an int [] source of RGBA data

```
int offset=0; // offset into the 'dest' array of bytes

for (...) // loop through your source array of ints 
{
    // get this current int value as rgba_val
    int rgba_val = (whatever your RGBA source is..is it wb1.Pixels?)

    dest[offset] = (rgba_val & 0xff) >> 24;
    dest[offset+1] = (rgba_val & 0x00ff) >> 16;
    dest[offset+2] = (rgba_val & 0x0000ff) >> 8;
}
```

Comment: Basically in this example, previewBuffer1 is a grayscale image. I want to copy the same values to RGB values, so that the RGB image mimcs the grayscale image. In your code, the issue is, dest should be a pointer to 8-bit values. Whereas "wb1.Pixels", the location where I need to store it is int[]

Answer (score 1):

I guess the below will work out for me:

```
//previewBuffer1 is of type byte[]
WriteableBitmap wb1 = new WriteableBitmap(nVidWidth, nVidHeight);
int k=0;
// wb1.Pixels is of type int[] by default
//byte* data = (byte*) wb1.Pixels;  // ****NOT REQUIRED ANYMORE***
for (int i=0; i<nVidHeight; i++){
    for (int j=0; j<nVidWidth; j++){
        int grayscaleval = (int) previewBuffer1[k];
        wb1.Pixels[k] = ((grayscaleval) | (grayscaleval<<8) | (grayscaleval<<16) | (0xFF<<24)); // 0xFF is for alpha blending value

        k++;
    }
}
```

Atleast logically seems to be fine. Yet to try it out.

Comment: I can confirm that the above works, and is probably the best solution for my application.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to convert your int array into bytes array

```
WriteableBitmap wb1 = new WriteableBitmap(100, 100);
int[] pixels = wb1.Pixels;
byte[] data = new byte[pixels.Length];
for (int i= 0; i < pixels.Length;i ++)
{
    data[i] = (byte)pixels[i];
}
```

Comment: I want to finally store the stuff into int array. wb1 is an int[], but the every interger entry is an RGBA value. I want to manipulate the RGBA value in place in order to later display it in the Image window. The above solution would not work for me. Thanks anyways.